# PHP. How to use function result as variable?

Tags: php, function, variables

This function returns url: `<?php get_theme_url(); ?>`. How can I use it as variable?

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
 $a = get_theme_url();
 $files = glob( '$a/tariffs/tariff-b*.php' );
 foreach( $files as $file ) {
  include( $file );
  echo $tariff_about;     
?>
```

---

**Update:**

Thanks! I'll use double quotes.

But now both `<?php get_theme_url(); ?>` and

```
<?php
 $a = get_theme_url();
 $files = glob( $a."/tariffs/tariff-b*.php" );
 foreach( $files as $file ) { include( $file );
  echo $tariff_about; }
?>
```

returns just `http://localhost/`.

What can it be?

Comment: you're missing your closing bracket on that foreach

Comment: the single quotes doesn't proccess the variables. use double quotes.

Comment: See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in the PHP manual

Answer (score 5):

change line2 to this:

```
$files = glob( "$a/tariffs/tariff-b*.php" );
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason it's not working is because variables are not parsed inside single-quotes. Try this instead:

```
$files = glob($a."/tariffs/tariff-b*.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign it to a variable!

```
$files = glob("$a/tariffs/tariff-b*.php");
```

And give a `}` at the end for the `foreach`!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try separating the variable and the string or using double quotes instead of single quotes. Also, check that the path is correct and the returned value is indeed the URL

```
$files = glob($a."/tariffs/tariff-b*.php");
```

Comment: Thanks! But now both `<?php get_theme_url(); ?>` and

    `<?php
     $a = get_theme_url();
     $files = glob( $a."/tariffs/tariff-b*.php" );
      foreach( $files as $file ) {
      include( $file );
      echo $tariff_about;     
     }
    ?>`  
  
returns just `http://localhost/`.

I mean that you could be right that returned value is not a url. However, what can it be?

Comment: I'm not sure, but most often the problem we think we have is only a byproduct of a different issue. (c'est la vie)